# An invalid parameter error at msvcr120.dll (Building Tesseract Lib in 64bit Windows)

Tags: c++, tesseract, tiff, libtiff, leptonica

I have already raised the inquiry to Tesseract Forum, but whether I can have a clue for the error, I raise the issue at this forum again. As this is my favorite forum in solving the problems.

I have a problem somehow related to the tesseract lib.

The problem is at libtiff one of the components used in leptonica library.

I followed exactly what is described [here](http://www.libtiff.org/build.html)

in building libtiff for my 64bit windows.

```
C:\LIBTIFF\LIBTIFF> nmake /f makefile.vc
C:\LIBTIFF\LIBTIFF> cd ..\tools
C:\LIBTIFF\TOOLS> nmake /f makefile.vc
```

Build is ok. 
Using tiff lib and I built leptonica lib and tessearact lib for 64bit windows.
Once I run my application using tesseract lib, I got error at tiff lib and the error is

"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA966FDD27 (msvcr120.dll) in TessarActOCR_test.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal."

The error is happening at lseek in the following function. The function is located in `tiffio.c`

```
static TIFF *
fopenTiff(FILE        *fp,tif_win32.c
          const char  *modestring)
{
l_int32  fd;

    PROCNAME("fopenTiff");

    if (!fp)
        return (TIFF *)ERROR_PTR("stream not opened", procName, NULL);
    if (!modestring)
        return (TIFF *)ERROR_PTR("modestring not defined", procName, NULL);

    if ((fd = fileno(fp)) < 0)
        return (TIFF *)ERROR_PTR("invalid file descriptor", procName, NULL);
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

    return TIFFFdOpen(fd, "TIFFstream", modestring);
}
```

What could be wrong with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I solved all problems and tesseract lib is working at my 64bit pc and project. The solution for me is step by step following the discussions in this [link](http://www.leptonica.org/vs2008doc/building-image-libraries.html) during preparing the dependencies. Then leptonica lib is built and then link to tesseract to build tesseract lib. Now all are working well.